# How to read an Image using CUDA programming?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, image-processing, parallel-processing, cuda

I am very beginner in CUDA. I just want to know how to read an image using CUDA programming? I am having NVidia Geforce 860 M, Installed Visual Studio 2012, CUDA 7.5.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You don't.  You can simply use a known C or C++ library, like ImageMagick, OpenCV, etc. then transfer the image data into global memory after.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only do it via a CPU and then transfer the image to the CUDA board's memory. CUDA boards do not provide access to the file system.

You will need to read the file using C++ functions and then pass the pointer of the image pixels Array to CUDAMEMCPY function.This will transfer the image from the CPU memory to the GPU Global memory.

Comment: That's right. You can't do it. This is the only method currently.